# Generate table with checked box using HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I am using HTML to generate checkbox for subjects and I want the user to choose the subject that he want to take and the information table is subject, courses, day and time, date this step is ok.

I have problem how to take checked box and generate table for his choices using button. (If he press the button will generate the table that it has the checked boxes). I have to use Javascript but I don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

Si when user clicks on submit this will générate a java script fonction that will do thé work by creating a table  with maximum size  Being thé size of thé table if thé user checks everything and then takes every selected item ans copies it into thé array  without forgetting thé incrementation in thé loop 
 i hope that this will help you :)

Comment: I know that i have to use javascript but i could not figure it out how i will do it.Could you help me